# knockout.js css binding - how to add element state like focus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I know how to add a css classes like:

```
 .active{
   //...style change
 }
```

by using css-binding with knockout.js

It works like:

```
 <div class='liveExample' data-bind='click: changeStyles, css:
 {selected:isSelected}'>
     Some Content
 </div>
```

But how do I have to add element state classes like

```
.flat a:hover,
.flat a:hover:after, .flat a.active:after,
.flat a:focus{
    //style change
}
```

with knockout.js css-binding?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `:hover` CSS selector do not work use the *event binding* with `mouseover` and `mouseout`:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

Comment: Thanks. But I was actually seeking to make ".flat a:focus" and ".flat a:focus:after" work. The thing is, when I inspect the element on chrome, I see that the "active" class is added when the object is clicked when I add the "data-bind='click: changeStyles, css:{selected:isSelected}", but I am not sure how to make the ".flat a:focus" and ".flat a:focus:after" work when I do the same thing